# InDesign - Arrange doesn't work with stroke applied to frame

Tags: adobe-indesign, stroke

I'm hoping someone has the answer to this.

I have a frame with a stroke around it, and I want to position a text box with the word 'bird' in front of it. There is no colour fill, but I don't think that matters. The 'frame with stroke' and 'bird' are on the same layer but I can't arrange the word to the front. If I drag 'bird' off to the side, it appears, and also appears when dragged in front of other text boxes, but won't show in front of frame with stroke.

I also tried putting them on separate layers but that doesn't help.

I searched this problem and found a couple of suggestions, one being to unlock all on spread, but nothing is locked and this is a new document created to try and figure out this problem, so no other lurking problems.

Thank you in advance for any suggestions, and please ask if I have not included any info that would help find solutions.

Comment: A bit difficult to follow. Why not [edit](http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/posts/85222/edit) and add a screenshot, so we don't assume the wrong things here.

Comment: Can't you just add a stroke to the text frame containing the word? That makes it all 1 object.

Comment: If its 2 _objects_ you have, one with a stroke and one with the text, then agree with Scott's reply and just put a stroke on the text object (or frame), then just remove the other object.

Answer (score 3):

It looks like a wrapping "issue".
Check your "frame with stroke" has no Text Wrap applied.
[image: wrap1]

If for some reason, you need to keep the text wrap option on in your "stroke frame", then select your "bird frame", go Object > Text Frame Options and tick "Ignore Text Wrap":

[image: wrap2]